# Preparing to distribute my first game, gets error 0xc000007b when trying to run in test environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment, cocos2d-x, game-development

I've made a game with Cocos2dx and compiled it for Release/Win32 in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019. I've created a virtual machine in Hyper-V (for figuring out what DLLs I need) that runs Windows 10 Pro N. In the test machine I've installed every redistributable Visual C++ package (I think) since 2008, so: 2008 (x86/x64), 2010 (x86/64), 2012 (x86/x64), 2013 (x86/x64), 2015-2019 (x86/x64), but it still gives me the error 0xc000007b when I try to run the app. Strangely, it complains if I don't put `vcruntime140d.dll` in the app folder, which is odd because the app is compiled for Release, but that file has a `d` at the end of it, which means it's for apps compiled for Debug, right? I don't know what's going on and I was hoping it would work with all those VC++ packages installed. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: If it is complaining about missing debug DLL files then it is linked against them. Check your build settings again and make sure you're not linking against any 3rd party debug libraries. I'd consider removing the last sentence of your question, this isn't a "share your strats" kinda site.

Comment: Last time I got this error, it was because of a mix of 32 and 64 bit DLLs. Make sure you have your binary and all DLLs in 32 or 64 bit, but not a mix. Look at project properties if you don't know if you are compiling in 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: QutentinC was right. One of the dlls were actually compiled for Debug; websockets.dll. I managed to find a version of it online that was compiled for Release and that made the 0xc000007b error disappear. But I also had to install VC++ x86 redistributable packages for 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015-2019.